# How to change UITextField size inside UIViewRepresentable in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit, swift4

I want to make a simple custom UITextField and I can't figure out how to set its height.

The problem is the UITextField expands to fill parent, and I realise I can set `.frame()` modifier on the `UINumberTextView`, but that isn't a good solution because you don't need to do that on a SwiftUI TextField. I'm beyond frustrated on this as I haven't found an answer anywhere and it's such a simple problem.

Here's my code - setting `textfield.frame` has no effect whatsoever.

```
struct UINumberTextView: UIViewRepresentable {

    @Binding var text: String

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextField {
        let textfield = UITextField()
        textfield.keyboardType = .numberPad
        textfield.frame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: .max, height: 44))
    
        return textfield
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextField, context: Context) {
        uiView.text = text
    }
}
```

Here's how the preview looks like

[image: Here's how this code looks in the preview.]

Answer (score 9):

You have to change the compression resistance priority

```swift
textField.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this one, been searching for it quite some time!